# show jquery thickbox when submitting form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, thickbox

I have form to upload images..
what i want is to process the form by ajax and after success show jquery [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do the ajax-call, and define a callback-function.

In the callback-function call this method:

```
function tb_show(caption, url, imageGroup)
```

this normally should show the tickbox

Make the ajax-call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yoururl.php",
  cache: false,
  success: function(){ // --> this defines what function needs to be called when the ajaxcall was successful.
    // note that you'll need to fill the variables caption, url and imagegroup here. I don't know what they should be in your case.
    function tb_show(caption, url, imageGroup);
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you get my idea. but could you explain the solution in more detail, please. thanx again..

Comment: i follow your instruct it appear just the loading image.. the image (provided by url ) is'n appear..

Comment: first try to show an alert to check if your ajax does work properly work.

Comment: the ajax work properly, it just download image appear.. the actual image doesn't appear.